# Higher Order Components and Authenticate Routes

Tags: reactjs

I am creating Higher Order Components in React and making sure that user cannot access the protected routes. Everything works fine but I am unsure where to put the code for checking the redux state. Currently, in the code below I have placed all the code in componentDidMount. This is because componentWillMount is deprecated. Is this the best place to check because componentDidMount is triggered after the component has been mounted.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

export default function(ComposedComponent) {

  class Authenticate extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {

      if(!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
        this.props.history.push('/')
      }

    }

    render() {
      return (
        <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
      )
    }
  }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated
  }
}


return connect(mapStateToProps)(Authenticate)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the correct state is available at construction, you can do the redirect in the constructor:

```
class Authenticate extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      if(!props.isAuthenticated) {
         props.history.push('/')
      }
   }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the purpose of React Router `Redirect` component:

```
render() {
  return !this.props.isAuthenticated ? (
    <Redirect to="/" />
  ) : (
    <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
  )
}
```